# how to access layout data in other pages other page data in layout in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have routes as below

```
{path:'',component:MenuComponent, outlet: 'menu'} ,


{path:'',redirectTo:'/',pathMatch:'full'},


{path:'',component:HomeComponent},
{path:':section',component:ListingComponent}
```

app.component.html as below

```
<div class="slider-panel"><router-outlet></router-outlet></div>
<router-outlet name="menu"></router-outlet>
```

how can i access menu data in listingcomponent and listing data in menu.

I referred https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction and edited my child as below
                 import { Component,OnInit,Provider ,HostListener,Input} from 
                 '@angular/core';

```
              import{MenuComponent} from 
               '../shared/layout/footer/menu.component';

             export class SectionBasedListingComponent implements OnInit {
               @Input('menus') menu:Array<Menu>;
              ngOnInit()
             {
               console.log(this.menu);
             }
           }
```

My parentcomponent is

```
                import { Component, OnInit, Provider, ViewChild, 
                ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
                export class  MenuComponent implements OnInit
                {
                public _menus: Array<Menu> = [];
                  ngOnInit() {
                this._service.GetRegionWiseMenu("3").
               subscribe(
               res => {

                   this._menus = res;
                });
               }
                }
```

Got undefined as output for this.menu

thanks

Comment: The documentation (https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) has examples. Have you read it and its examples? If you haven't, then do. If you have, then adding another example here won't help. So ask a concrete question, with your code.

Comment: thanks.I tired and got error.Pls see updated question

Comment: Of course you have undefined. The listing is not a child of the menu at all. And you're not passing any input to the listing component (you can't, since it's not the child of anything, since it's created and inserted by the router). Don't just try random things. Read the documentation carefully, and apply it where it makes sense.

Comment: I got it.they are passing data to child from parent as  <app-hero-child *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
      [hero]="hero"
      [master]="master">
    </app-hero-child>.but In my case ,I am having menu as common layout.In this case I can't pass data from menu to  SectionBasedListingComponent.Pls see my app.component.html,one router-outlet is for menu.another one is SectionBasedListingComponent or any other component.In this case how can i pass data pls help me

Comment: hi,I am new to angular.can u pls help me